# Node.js - Find home directory in platform agnostic way

Tags: node.js, filesystems, platform-independent, home-directory, platform-agnostic

Process.platform returns "win32" for Windows. On Windows a user's home directory might be C:\Users[USERNAME] or C:\Documents and Settings[USERNAME] depending on which version of Windows is being used. On Unix this isn't an issue.

Comment: Does Mac OS X retain the Unix method or does it require something different too?

Comment: @hippietrail Mac OS X uses HOME like every other Unix.

Answer (score 475, accepted):

As mentioned in [a more recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32556337/103396), the preferred way is now simply:

```javascript
const homedir = require('os').homedir();
```

[Original Answer] Why not use the `USERPROFILE` environment variable on win32?

```javascript
function getUserHome() {
  return process.env[(process.platform == 'win32') ? 'USERPROFILE' : 'HOME'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Just installed Node.js locally, as building a basic server on Cloud9 is not following my little tutorial (of course)... and had NO IDEA where to put my files.  You are the man! (I assume)

Comment: In 0.10.33 win 64bit this does not work.  I have USERPROFILE and HOME set to C:  My company forces me to have a HOMEDRIVE/HOMEPATH set to a network share H:.  For some reason node prefers H:.

Comment: I have a viscerally negative reaction to this answer and the second most popular one. If you are using node.js, then IMHO, you should favor npm modules like os.homedir() and osenv.home() (both mentioned below). If you look at the source for os.homedir(), you'll see that it's not this simple.

Comment: This is not a platform agnostic means.

Comment: wrapping a `path.resolve()` might provide some normalization in terms of trailing slashes, potentially odd forward/backslashes, etc... (especially if you got file operations in mind, after getting this info)

Comment: Ah what, oh what, does one do if on a Mac? There it is `/Users/yourname`. I kinda wish this answer would just be removed.

Comment: Or: `const { homedir } = require('os'); console.log(homedir());`

Comment: I used to use process.env.HOMEPATH on Windows. But then I ran the same app with administrative privileges and got an error because for some reason process.env.HOMEPATH  value was undefined.  So beware it is risky to rely on values of environment variables, they are not part of any standard.

Answer (score 284):

[`os.homedir()`](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_homedir) was added [by this PR](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/1791) and is part of the public 4.0.0 release of nodejs.

---

Example usage:

```
const os = require('os');

console.log(os.homedir());
```

Comment: Got it. Added sources because `os.homedir()` is a pretty darn new toy.

Comment: should be accepted answer as it is compatible cross platform

Answer (score 83):

Well, it would be more accurate to rely on the feature and not a variable value. Especially as there are 2 possible variables for Windows.

```
function getUserHome() {
  return process.env.HOME || process.env.USERPROFILE;
}
```

**EDIT**: as mentioned in a more recent answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/32556337/103396 is the right way to go (`require('os').homedir()`).

Comment: On my Windows 7 machine, HOMEPATH and USERPROFILE return the same thing (C:\\Users\\Username). HOME returns undefined. On my Mac HOME returns /Users/Username and HOMEPATH and USERPROFILE return undefined.

Comment: on my windows 7 machine, HOMEPATH returns `\users\name` and USERPROFILE has `c:\users\name`. So this method is not as accurate and robust as @maerics'

Answer (score 16):

Use `osenv.home()`. It's maintained by isaacs and I believe is used by npm itself.

https://github.com/isaacs/osenv

Comment: `oshome` uses [`os-homedir`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/os-homedir) under the hood, if you want only that functionality.

Answer (score 4):

```
getUserRootFolder() {
  return process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH || process.env.USERPROFILE;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in some cases try to use this:

```
this.process.env.USERPROFILE
```

or

```
this.nw.process.env.USERPROFILE
```

i.e. add this or this.nw before process