# Where to place configuration files for Node.js global module

Tags: javascript, node.js, configuration

I'm creating a global module that will offer a few command line executables, and I'm wondering where is the best place to store configuration options for the module. For example, `npm` has the [`npm adduser`](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-adduser.html) command that registers a user account (in the `.npmrc` file located in the user's home directory). My question is this: if I need to store configuration and/or cached files, is the best practice to use something like:

```
function getUserHome() {
  return process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH || process.env.USERPROFILE;
}
```

To [find the user's home directory in platform agnostic way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080085/node-js-find-home-directory-in-platform-agnostic-way), and then create my configuration folder in there (presumably prefixed by `.`, so it is hidden on unix machines)?