# Node.js - How to cross-platform find the 'desktop' directory path?

Tags: node.js, path, operating-system, desktop

As mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/32556337/103396, `require('os').homedir()` is the way to get the user's home directory.

In Windows the desktop path would be on `user_home_dir/Desktop`:

```
require('path').join(require('os').homedir(), 'Desktop')
```

Will this work on other platforms?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late reply.

Yes, it does work cross-platform. So far, I've tested it on Windows 10 and Ubuntu, both have positive results.

See:

[Windows 10 Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fSer.png)

[Ubuntu Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ml8Aj.png)

Comment: This would definitely **NOT** work on localized Linux platforms. For instance, with the `it_IT` locale the desktop would be located in `$HOME/Scrivania`.

Answer (score 0):

Works on macOS as well; in case it doesn't work with Desktop, you can of course fallback to `homedir()` base directory:

```
import { homedir } from 'os';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';
import { resolve } from 'path';

const getDesktopOrHomeDir = () => {
  const homeDir = resolve(homedir())
  const desktopDir = resolve(homedir(), 'Desktop')
  if (!existsSync(desktopDir)) {
    return homeDir;
  }
  return desktopDir;
}

writeFile(resolve(getDesktopOrHomeDir(), 'myfile.txt'), 'foobar')
```