# How can I use ~ (home dir) in a cross-platform compatible way in an npm script?

Tags: node.js, windows, bash, npm, git-bash

I'm trying to copy `~/.aws` into my docker container. But I'm on a Windows machine running `git-bash` and that seems to be causing some issues.

Two things I've tried so far:

`"d-aws-copy": "docker cp ~/.aws constraint-listener:/usr/src/app"`

Result: `GetFileAttributesEx C:\work\project-name\~: The system cannot find the file specified.`

`"d-aws-copy": "docker cp /c/Users/user-name-here/.aws constraint-listener:/usr/src/app",`

Result: `GetFileAttributesEx C:\c: The system cannot find the file specified.`

All the solutions I've seen involving tilde expansion are for node code, not for command line npm scripts.

If I run `docker cp ~/.aws constraint-listener:/usr/src/app` from bash it works fine. But inside of an npm script it crashes as seen above.

How can I get `~` to work in an npm script on a Windows machine?

Comment: I think this should help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9081436/1262789

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to call `bash` directly:

```
"d-copy-aws": "bash -c \"docker cp ~/.aws constraint-listener:/root\" && echo aws credentials copied",
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling out from Node you are using the standard shell, probably CMD on Windows. It won't string interpolate the tilde. Use a platform independent variable instead or detect the platform and look up the value of either $HOME or $WINHOME using process.env - depending on the OS.

Edit: didn't see it was an NPM script ... Missed the tag. Thought the question mentioned Node.