# Node.js - How to find the desktop path?

Tags: javascript, node.js

As the mentioned [Node.js - Find home directory in platform agnostic way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9080085/284199) question, we can find the home folder via this code:

```
const homedir = require('os').homedir();
```

But how can I find the desktop folder whatever language is it in Windows? Because in windows desktop folder name is differ to languages.

Comment: Actually, the name is always Desktop, regardless of language. However Windows creates a virtual alias for the folder. In Portuguese is "Área de Trabalho", but you can access with %USERPROFILE%\Desktop

Comment: @RobsonFrança Can you write as answer, because that explains as clear as possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the name is always Desktop, regardless of language. However Windows creates a virtual alias for the folder. In Portuguese is "Área de Trabalho", but you can access with %USERPROFILE%\Desktop

Comment: I came across this thread while looking for a reliable way to find the location of "Desktop". For as long as I can remember, this answer was the correct answer. However, I recently got a new laptop at work and at some point during the setup, it decided to sync my Desktop folder on OneDrive. As such, my Desktop location became "%USERPROFILE%\OneDrive\Desktop" and I had no "%USERPROFILE\Desktop" directory at all. I managed to undo that and move Desktop to my profile directory. But it is no longer possible to blindly assume the location is a folder directly under the user profile directory.

Comment: This could also happen when you sync your user folders on Dropbox. I'll check another way to get that information.

Comment: After searching npm, I found a package called "platform-folders". It uses node-gyp and uses the Windows SHGetKnownFolderPath function that has been available since Vista. This function correctly returns the location using the value FOLDERID_Desktop for the  REFKNOWNFOLDERID argument. I considered referencing the Registry but one Shell key has a warning in it about not using it to find folders and the other key seems to be incomplete. It looks like the API call is the only way to reliably find the Desktop location in Windows.

Answer (score 17):

Try this

```
const homeDir = require('os').homedir(); // See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/os
const desktopDir = `${homeDir}/Desktop`;
console.log(desktopDir);
```

It should work on Windows and MacOS.

Comment: You have an error in your code: `homeDir !== homedir`

Answer (score 4):

## NPM

With npm, try [platform-folders](https://www.npmjs.com/package/platform-folders)

```
npm install platform-folders
```

```
import getPath from 'platform-folders';
console.log(getPath('downloads'));
```

## Node

If you want to do it with raw node, the following works most of the time on all major platforms, but there are a few things to keep in mind:

It is does not have reliability equivalent to `homedir()` for these reasons:

1. All platforms have a home directory, but not all platforms have a desktop, and not all desktops are also folders.
2. `homedir()` will always point to the home folder even on future versions of a platform, but the code below will stop working on platforms that in future versions change where they put the default desktop.
3. `homedir()` will work even if the user configures a home directory in a strange location, but if a user configures the desktop to be in an unusual location, the following does not work.
4. This might fail to work on some platforms in some non-english locales, but in Windows, the desktop is accessible by "Desktop" in all languages.

```
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');
const desktopDir = path.join(os.homedir(), "Desktop");
console.log(desktopDir);
```

Example Output:

```
C:\Users\jschmoe\Desktop
or
/home/jschmoe/Desktop
```

Comment: what if I have moved my desktop to other drive? ie B:/desktop