# Get local system home directory path from server

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I have a server running, I want to get the local system file path where aws server is running using node js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js - Find home directory in platform agnostic way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080085/node-js-find-home-directory-in-platform-agnostic-way)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the path to the current script with Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133243/how-do-i-get-the-path-to-the-current-script-with-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

Use `process.cwd()` which is also documented here: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem:

```
__dirname
```

Check with a console log whether it's what you wanted or not.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of achieving this. One of them is you can use this package,

> app-root-path

Install the package with the command :

```
npm i -S app-root-path                   //install the package
```

Use package where you required :

```
var appRoot = require('app-root-path');  //require package 
console.log(appRoot);                    //use variable as string
```

You can import the package and use variable where ever you require inside the app.
You can check this package documentation visiting this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/app-root-path).