# Javscript fs module: where is output being written to?

Tags: javascript, fs, absolute-path, pathname

I'm using the `fs` filesystem JS module to write to a file. I want this file to be in the `~/Desktop` folder, so I do this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
let a = "text"
fs.writeFile('~/Desktop/output.txt', a, () => {})
```

This runs with no errors, but I don't see an `output.txt` file on my Desktop, or anywhere in my system. It works fine when I just do `output.txt` instead of `~/Desktop/output.txt`; it saves the output in a file `output.txt` in my current directory.

Does anyone know what's happening here?

Comment: I don't think nodejs understands the `~` (correct me if I'm wrong) but as you have tagged, you need to use an absolute path. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080085/node-js-find-home-directory-in-platform-agnostic-way you can use this to get the home directory

Comment: Thanks to both ^^ that does work. So does the answer below with expand-tilde.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node doesn't expand the bash specific shortcut tilde ("~") to your home directory.

Specify the full path or use a package like [expand-tilde](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expand-tilde).