# Node.js - Find Current Working Directory (CWD) in platform agnostic way

Tags: node.js, filesystems, platform-independent, cwd, platform-agnostic

Basically the same quest for [Node.js - Find home directory in platform agnostic way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080085/node-js-find-home-directory-in-platform-agnostic-way)
but with CWD

Answer (score 0):

To get the current working directory
with Node.js
, you can use the

```
process.cwd()
```

method. This method returns the current working directory as a string representing the absolute path
of the folder where the Node.js process is currently running.